# Intellij IDEA Auto-Comments after each code block ( "}" character)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments

```
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(

    ), //Scaffold
  )); //MaterialApp
}
```

I didn't add comments, IDE did and I don't want to. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance, check box 'Show closing labels'.

Restart IDEA